# How do I change the button text automatically with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, schedule, jquery-events

I want to change a button text: when clicked on the button it must show "Adding" and 2-3 seconds later I need it to show "Added".

Here is a sample code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $('.addcartbtn').toggle(function() {
        $(this).val('Adding');
    },

    // How to make the button text automatically change after 3 seconds?
    function() {
        $(this).val('Added');
    });

});
```

Comment: Some HTML code would be appreciated

Comment: What you are doing sounds like faking functionality. Is there any action after which the button label should change? It is not the best idea to rely on timing functions, when instead you could have listened to an event/user action.

Comment: Hi @feeela, Yes not best idea but i need easy solution. This way is best for me. Thanks your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this simple code:

```
$('.addcartbtn').on("click",function(){
   $(this).val("Adding....");
     setTimeout(function(){
        $('.addcartbtn').val("Added");}, 2000);
});
```

Comment: This will set "Added" in every `.addcartbtn` on the page, not only on the clicked one.

Answer (score 4):

### [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Z746j/1/)

I made a fiddle for you. There's an example with two cases you may need, since you didn't explain properly which kind of button you have. Check it out

### JS

```
// This one works for <input> tags
$('input.addcartbtn').click(function(e){
    $(this).val('Adding..');
    setTimeout(function(){
       $(e.target).val('Clicked!');
    }, 3000);
});

// This one works for <button> tags
$('button.addcartbtn').click(function(e){
   $(this).text('Adding..');
   setTimeout(function(){
       $(e.target).text('Clicked!');
    }, 3000);
});
```

### HTML

If you have an input tag

```
<input type="submit" class="addcartbtn" value="Click Me" />
```

If you have a button tag

```
<button class="addcartbtn">Click me</button>
```

Comment: That's not quite what he needs

Comment: Ups! Forgot the timeout. My fault

Answer (score 3):

You can do this:

```
$(function () {
    var that = $('.addcartbtn');  // cache the element
    that.text('Adding..'); // change its text to "Adding.."
    setTimeout(function () { // create a function to be executed after...
        that.text('Added'); 
    }, 3000); // ... 3 seconds
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/u28NW/)

Comment: glad to have helped you `:)`  @ErdalBakkal

Comment: i need clicked button after auto changed ..For Example Button test default Checkout.. When I cliked Adding.. Added